# generate new session token everytime

Tags: python, python-requests

im writing code on python so whats my problem rn, im making post request to url, but everytime i make request i need new session token and hash expiry, [Here is picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KQfo.png)

i can regenerate it with burp, just reloading page, but i cant make request to generate it automaticly,  [Here is picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xTTc.png)

i wonder if there is any way to do that with python?
heres my code for requesting:

```
cookies = {
    'TS013f0544': '01c54dc2355dd3062ce715bf51edb1859beb8c7e24cfb18f87cfba44756bf60a18b0c025c4360c45cf9c4d6be0e25d51be1cce80f1',
    'TS013f0544028': '018238f46cf89de85b8e0f979e12ffcf49a040e01ce02823662364bf5e2c5bde5a1a45f4b9a200e0a319e7ea003f51b68f64381892',
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.beanstream.com',
    'Content-Length': '207',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"(Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="98"',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Linux"',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://www.beanstream.com',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://www.beanstream.com/scripts/PaymentProfile/webform.asp?serviceVersion=1.0&operationType=N&merchantId=311470013&customerCode=&trnAmount=0&ref1=&ref2=&ref3=&ref4=&ref5=239118&hashValue=B36CCC24A4238F9AED1B03A883325A0F345A4F2F&trnReturnURL=https%3A%2F%2Fepaymentservice.calgary.ca%2FProfilePayment%2FProfileCreationConfirmation.aspx&trnComments=&errorPage=https://citystore.calgary.ca/ctestore/checkout/payment?',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'close',
}


data = f'sessionToken=90CFDFD2-ECCD-4B54-AEF26C77EFE2C&trnLanguage=eng&hashExpiry=202202221555&paymentAction=&trnCardType=MC&trnCardOwner=asd&trnCardNumber={cc[1]}&trnExpMonth={month[1]}&trnExpYear={year[1]}&trnCardCvd={cvv[1]}'


response = requests.post('https://www.beanstream.com/scripts/PaymentProfile/xt_process_customer.asp', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

i think that if burp can generate that session token, python can do it to.

**Code is for educational purpose only!**

Comment: Have you tried uuid? https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: uuid for whats, sorry i cant understand, i mean is'nt uuid just generating uuid of system? how can i get that session token with uuid.

Comment: i forgot to add, i also need hash expiry, that is on first picture, i think thats current date and time

Comment: Sorry, I thought you just wanted some random ID. If you want a new Session, then create an actual `Session()` object. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: i can get headers and text with that but i cant get data, in burp it shows that after headers comes session token and hash expiry, i need to get value of that, is it possible?

Comment: `56fc9636-1a0c-4883-b997-034505656096` is just a UUIDv4 value. So, like I said, use the uuid module. The token value itself doesn't really matter as it doesn't represent any encrypted data